# I am getting Template Does Not Exist at / when I'm running my server in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, atom-editor

When I run server I get **Template Does Not Exist at /** for my index.html page. Same problem occurs for other templates as well. 
I've tried the solutions for previously asked similar questions like checking the template directory and installed apps in settings.py file but nothing seems working.
Also, when I create a new project folder at some other location and copy all the code there, it usually works.
This is my folder tree:

[image]

I'm currently learning Django and new at stack overflow. Any help would be appreciated?

Here is my urls.py code for project folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from basic_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'basic_app/',include('basic_app.urls')),
]
```

Here is my urls.py file under basic_app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from basic_app import views

app_name= 'basic_app'
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^register/$',views.register,name='register')
]
```

Here is my views.py file code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms  import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm

def index(request):
    return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')

def register(request):
    registered= False

    if request.method=='POST':
        user_form= UserForm(data= request.POST)
        profile_form= UserProfileInfoForm(data= request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
             user= user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile= profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic= request.FILES['profile_pics']
            profile.save()

            registered= True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors ,profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form= UserForm()
        profile_form= UserProfileInfoForm()


    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,
                                                    'registered':registered})
```

Here is my settings.py file code for templates:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

This is my Installed app list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'basic_app',
]
```

Also this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: show us your `urls.py` and `views.py`

Comment: And the settings related to templates.

Comment: I have added my files code in the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your settings.py check the directory pointed by **TEMPLATE_DIR** so that you can configure where exactly it is ponting to.

```py
print(TEMPLATE_DIR)
```

Then in **views.py**:

```py
def index(request):
    return render(request,'folder/my_html_file.html')
```

So django renders the template from.

> TEMPLATE_DIR + "folder/my_html_file.html"

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks. I got my mistake. Actually I created templates folder under the folder with same name as the main project folder. I found the mistake by printing the template directory. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think in admin just do this

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

and your view should be something like this

```
return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,
                                                    'registered':registered})
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default configuration settings, the templates are supposed to be in `learning_users/basic_app/templates/basic_app/` and accessed like the following:

```
return render(request, `basic_app/index.html`, {})
```

where `index.html` is your template name.
The directory structure here may seem a little redundant at first but you can also change it using the `settings.py` configuration file.
In your directory, the templates folder is placed directly inside the project folder (i.e. `learning_users`). Unless you have modified the configuration files to change the templates' path, this would result in an Error.

Comment: But my TEMPLATE_DIR says **"os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')"**which I think should result in the same path as my tree.

Answer (score 0):

but perhaps you can do this sure it works in your settings.py file add this line to the installed apps

'basic_app.apps.Basic_appConfig'